# How to show that ODE is Separable

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I have an ODE: $$xy'= y+2x^3 \sin\big(\frac{y}{x}\big)^2.$$
I have to show that this is separable.
I have introduced a function `u = y/x`. Then using `DivideSides` and `Simplify` I got the following equation: $$(ux)'= u+2x^2 \sin\big(\frac{y}{x}\big)^2.$$

> Now I have to use *product rule* for the left side of the equation and get a form of Separable ODE. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Why not

1. Substitute $u=y/x$ programmatically:

   ```
   x y'[x] == y[x] + 2 x^3*Sin[y[x]/x]^2 /. y -> Function[x, u[x] x] // FullSimplify
   ```

$$2 x^2 \sin ^2(u(x))=x u'(x)$$

2. Express the derivative in Leibniz's notation (you can select the output and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to transform to pretty `TraditionalForm`):

   ```
   % /. {u[x] -> u, u'[x] -> Dt[u]/Dt[x]}
   ```

$$2 x^2 \sin ^2(u)=\frac{x du}{dx}$$

3. Multiply both sides:

   ```
    MultiplySides[%, Dt[x]/x/Sin[u]^2, Assumptions -> Dt[x]/x/Sin[u]^2 != 0]
   ```

$$2 x dx=\csc ^2(u)du$$